# Terraform, get value from map

Tags: terraform, argocd

Prompt me, please, how can I get separately a value for key `paswd-0`. I mean, I need separated values for password and username.

This is remote data from `data.terraform_remote_state.user_passwd.outputs.login_passwd`

```
output   = {
      paswd-0 = jsonencode(
            {
              password = "uGo="
              username = "git"
    }
        )
      paswd-1 = jsonencode(
            {
              password = "wM="
              username = "kun"
    }
        )
}
```

I'm trying this and get error `parameter: lookup() requires a map as the`

```
output "tetts" {
  value = lookup(tomap(data.terraform_remote_state.user_passwd.outputs.login_passwd.paswd-0), "password", null)
 }
```

Ideally I would go through of each value and fill these fields.

```
argocd_repositories = {
    [
    "private-repo" = {
      url      = "https://repo.git"
      username = "argocd"
      password = "access_token"
    },
    "git-repo" = {
      url      = "https://repo.git"
      password = "argocd_access_token"
      username = "admin"
    },
    "private-helm-chart" = {
      url      = "https://charts.jetstack.io"
      type     = "helm"
      username = "foo"
      password = "bar"
    },
    ]
  }
```

Comment: So you want only that one value?

Comment: Ideally I would go thought each and fill these fields
https://gist.github.com/rmalenko/d5486dba233bb9e1af2ea9d29ecb0b78

Comment: The first thing here is that for the key you probably need to use `["passwd-0"]`. Additionally, there are built-in functions `keys` and `values` which return a list of keys and values for a map, respectively. I am afraid I don't quite understand the problem you are trying to solve so not sure I can give the right answer.

Comment: How exactly `argocd_repositories` is constructed using your `output`? Its difficult to see a link between them.

Comment: @MarkoE when I get key=value from AWS secrets in output appears `jsonencode` which prevents run `lookup`
I think I need to find out how and remove `jsonencode` from `output`

Comment: You can do `jsondecode`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my comment, you can get the value from the data source by using the `jsondecode` built-in function [1]. You would have to update the output to look like the following:

```
output "tetts" {
  value = lookup(tomap(jsondecode(data.terraform_remote_state.user_passwd.outputs.login_passwd["paswd-0"]), "password", null)
 }
```

This is only to make it work as you intended it to. However, it will output only the value for the password. Since I do not have the remote state, I managed to get close to what you want with locals and the following:

```
locals {
  output = {
    paswd-0 = jsonencode(
      {
        password = "uGo="
        username = "git"
      }
    )
    paswd-1 = jsonencode(
      {
        password = "wM="
        username = "kun"
      }
    )
  }

  sorted_values = { for k, v in local.output : jsondecode(v).username => jsondecode(v).password }
}
```

Note that `jsondecode` is used on the values of the original map. Furthermore, since the JSON decoded values are also in a key value pair format, you can access the keys and corresponding values using the usual terraform notation (i.e., `jsondecode(v).username` and `jsondecode(v).password`). Using `terraform console`, the local `sorted_values` variable has the following look:

```
> local.sorted_values
{
  "git" = "uGo="
  "kun" = "wM="
}
```

I guess this is close to what you wanted to achieve with the `tomap` function.

---

[1] https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/jsondecode